# Override Hashing function

Tags: hazelcast

Is it possible to override the Hashing function of Hazelcast with CustomHashing Function?

I need my keys to be able to hash to a specific range of values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see [PartitionAware](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12.4/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/PartitionAware.html)

Be aware if your partitions aren't equally sized you'll cause yourself all sorts of problems.